# Calculate total CPU usage

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I have following specs:

```
CPU(s):                2
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
```

A process is using (according in `top`) 50%. How much is the total usage?
Is it: `50% / ((cpu * thead) * 100%)`? Meaning:
`50% / (( 1 * 2) * 100%)`

Comment: It's 50% of all the four threads combined. 100% means a single fully saturated CPU thread. 400% would mean all the four CPU threads saturated.

Comment: Some versions of top have an Irix/Solaris mode.  In Irix mode (default) 400% means 4 cores.  In Solaris mode, 50% means half the cpu cores.